# Formal proof for $q \land \neg q \vdash r \land \neg r$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, formal-proofs

Having some issue with some logic. The question is to formally prove;

$$q \land \neg q \vdash r \land \neg r$$

I've never done this before so would appreciate some help with it. No idea really where to start as $r \land \neg r$ doesn't exist on the left hand side of the equation. I guess I break down the left hand side first but then I don't know where to go.

Would really appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Thanks.

**Update**

Have attempted it myself but still not sure what to do. With the first part of the formula $q \land \neg q$ ... do I declare this as false? Really have no idea where to go with this, other than deducting the $q \land \neg q$ apart.

Would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks.

[Image of solution so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n88o8.jpg)

Comment: What proof systems you are using ? Natural deduction or ...

Comment: Note that disjunction introduction allows us to introduce arbitrary propositions in your proof. That is, $Q\vdash Q\lor R$.

Comment: natural deduction - sorry should have mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the contradiction $q \land \lnot q$, by $\lnot$-elimination, we have to derive $\bot$, and then apply $\bot$-elimination :

> $\dfrac \bot \varphi \ $, with $\varphi$ whatever,

to conclude.

---

*Proof*

1) $q \land \lnot q$ --- premise

2) $q$ --- from 1) by $(\land E)$

3) $\lnot q$ --- from 1) by $(\land E)$

4) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 2) by $(\lnot E)$

> 5) $r \land \lnot r$ --- from 4) by $(\bot E)$.

---

See [Natural Deduction: Rules](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) for the rules.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably find useful is to use RAA in some kind of form. From $q\land\neg q$ you can deduce both $q$ and $\neg q$. Assuming $\neg(r \land \neg r)$ would then lead to a contradiction (both $q$ and $\neg q$) and from that we could conclude that $r\land\neg r$.