# Formally prove the following equations using propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

p ∧ ¬p $\vdash$ q ∧ ¬q

p ∧ r ⇒ q ∧ r , p ∨ r ⇒ q ∨ r $\vdash$ p ⇒ q

I have literally been trying to figure these out all morning and I'm desperately stuck now. We have to prove them using propositional logic via the formal proof/natural deduction system. If anyone could help me out and explain how they reach their conclusion I'd be immeasurably grateful - thanks.

The ruleset used for this include:

and-elimination
and-introduction
or-elimination
or-introduction
<=>-introduction
<=>-elimination
=>-introduction
=>-elimination
¬-introduction
¬-elimination

Comment: What does the character "$\color{red}`$" mean?

Comment: For the first one, see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663143/formal-proof-for-q-%e2%88%a7-%c2%acq-%e2%8a%a2-r-%e2%88%a7-%c2%acr).

Comment: @GitGud Oh sorry it's meant to represent the semantic turnstile |-. For some reason it didn't display correctly

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok thank you I'll have a look at that link

Comment: @confusedbylogic123 Type `$\vdash$` to get $\vdash$.

Comment: @GitGud Edited the main post thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

For the second one, assume $p$ and derive $p \lor r$ by $\lor$-intro.

Then derive $q \lor r$ from the second premise.

Now we have to consider $q \lor r$ for $\lor$-elim.

From the "alternative" $q$, we have immediately $p \to q$.

From the alternative $r$ we get $p \land r$ and thus $q \land r$ from the first premise.

Now apply $\land$-elim to derive $q$ and then $p \to q$ again.

Thus, we may conclude by $\lor$-elim.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll run through the steps now and see if I can make sense of how I'm doing it